# How do I define PagerTitleStrip background in my custom theme?

Tags: android, android-styles

I am trying to define some color schemes in my custom themes. If user change a theme in runtime, these things will change-

- Layout Backgrounds
- PagerTitleStrip Background
- AutoCompleteTextView Background

How can I define attributes for those in my theme? I didn't find any. 
My `themes.xml` so far-

```
<style name="NotepadTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/searchbox_border_note_theme</item>

</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have solution?